# Hangman in Python 3

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, hangman

I started learning Python a couple of weeks ago and decided to make a game of Hangman.
Some of the features:

- Take in player name
- Allow them to pick and change difficulty level
- Play again when the game is over

I would love suggestions on how to make the code more pythonic and better overall.

```
import random
import sys

#Gallow printouts
gallows = ["_______\n|     |\n|     O\n|    -|-\n|     |\n|    / \\ \n|\n=======",
       "_______\n|     |\n|     O\n|    -|-\n|     |\n|    /\n|\n=======",
       "_______\n|     |\n|     O\n|    -|-\n|     |\n|\n|\n=======",
       "_______\n|     |\n|     O\n|    -|\n|     |\n|\n|\n=======",
       "_______\n|     |\n|     O\n|     |\n|     |\n|\n|\n=======",
       "_______\n|     |\n|     O\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=======",
       "_______\n|     |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=======",
      ]

# Lists containing the words for the game
five_letters = ['ankle', 'apple', 'birds', 'aunts', 'blood',
         'bones', 'forty', 'glitz', 'gnome', 'goats',
          'fairy', 'gator', 'glass', 'kneel', 'laces',
          'patio', 'party', 'taffy', 'zones', 'wages'
         ]
ten_letters = ['jackrabbit', 'maximizers', 'abnormally', 'abolishers', 'adrenaline',
        'california', 'basketball', 'friendship', 'renovation', 'skateboard',
        'understand', 'leadership', 'restaurant', 'generation', 'girlfriend',
        'vegetables', 'protection', 'trampoline', 'rainforest', 'instrument']
fifteen_letters = ['maneuverability', 'insubordination', 'excommunication', 'acclimatization',
             'rationalisation', 'mischievousness', 'kindheartedness', 'procrastinating',
            'confidentiality', 'instrumentation', 'inaccessibility', 'marginalization']

#Program Functions
def pick_diff():
    """Let the player pick and confirm a difficulty level."""
    prompt = "Pick a difficulty, please. (Easy, Medium, Hard)\n>"
    choice = ""
    while choice not in ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']:
        choice = input(prompt)
        choice = choice.lower()
    change_diff(choice)

def change_diff(level):
    """Allow the player a chance to change difficulty."""
    message = "\nYou picked " + level + ". Do you want to change it? [Y/N]\n>"
    answer = ""
    while answer not in ['y', 'n']:
        answer = input(message)
        answer = answer.lower()
    if answer == 'y':
        pick_diff()
    if answer == 'n':
        print("\nLET'S PLAY!\n")
        choose_word(level)

def choose_word(choice):
    """Assign the game word based on player difficulty choice."""
    if choice == 'easy':
        word = random.choice(five_letters)
    elif choice == 'medium':
        word = random.choice(ten_letters)
    elif choice == 'hard':
        word = random.choice(fifteen_letters)
    play_game(word)

def play_game(this_word):
    """Run the actual game of hangman."""
    word = list(this_word)
    blanks = "_" * len(word)
    blanks = list(blanks)
    guessed = []
    incorrect = 6
    while incorrect > 0:
        print("\n" + gallows[incorrect]
              + "\nYou have {} chances left.".format(incorrect)
              + "\nYour word: " + "".join(blanks)
              + "\nGuessed letters: " + ", ".join(guessed)
             )
        letter = input("Your guess: ").lower()
        if len(letter) == 1 and letter.isalpha():
            if letter in guessed:
                print("\n\nYou already guessed that!")
            elif letter in word:
                for index,character in enumerate(word):
                    blanks = list(blanks)
                    if character == letter:
                        blanks[index] = letter
                        current = "".join(blanks)
                        if blanks == word:
                            print("\n\nCONGRATULATIONS, YOU WON!!\nYour word was " + ''.join(word) + ".\n")
                            play_again()
            elif letter not in word:
                incorrect -= 1
                guessed.append(letter)
        else:
            print("\n\n!Only single letters allowed!\n\n")
    else:
        print(gallows[0])
        print("\nSorry " + player + ", your game is over!\nYour word was " + ''.join(word) + ".")
        play_again()

def play_again():
    """Offer the player a chance to play again."""
    repeat = input("Would you like to play again " + player + "? [Y/N]\n>").lower()
    if repeat == 'y':
        print("Let's play!")
        pick_difficulty()
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing! Have a great day!")
        sys.exit()

# Welcome the player, get their name and explain the game.
player = input("Let's play hangman! Please type your name.\n>").lower()
player = player.title()
print("\nHey, " + player + "!\nYou get six incorrect guesses before you lose.\nWhich difficulty would you like?\n  Easy - Five letter word\n  Medium - Ten letter word\n  Hard - Fifteen letter word")

# Select the difficulty and begin the game
difficulty = pick_diff()
```

Comment: python 2 or python 3? looks like python 3, please correct either the title or the tag

Comment: This code doesn't work — I think there's been some kind of copy–paste error. @Robert, can you fix it?

Comment: @Gareth Rees I'll have a look tonight. It was having a fit when I tried to paste it but I thought I correct it. It's also on GitHub here https://github.com/robwa10/Hangman

Answer (score 7):

Good work! I applaud you on maintaining readability and having a compartmentalized, functional program. From a glance I suggest this:

Lines 32 and similar `input()`'s: make them like `choice = input(prompt)`. As your code is now you must enter the `while` loop at least once.

Lines 34 and similar: you can do things like `choice = input("bla bla").lower()`, which you do later in the code anyways.

Lines 64 & 65: combine to `blanks = list("_" * len(word))`

Line 80: `blanks = list(blanks)` is not needed.

Line 83: `currents` is never used.

Lines 108 & 109: You can do `player = input("bla bla").title()"`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments! I´ve been doing some work with openpyxl these last few days and have realized the brevity of adding .lower(), etc. to the end of lines. And a definite thanks for pointing out where I forgot to delete line 83 after I changed the code above it.

Answer (score 2):

The code is good, big up, but the user doesn't know exactly how many words he or she is supposed to play with.

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
player = input("bla bla").lower()
player = player.title()
```

can be combined to

```
player = input("bla bla").title()
```

`title()` except form casing first letter of each word lowers the later ones

Answer (score 2):

Very good work I learned some new things checking out your code. I did notice one thing when running it on my end. I was not able to run the game again when it asks "would you like to play again"

line 116: `pick_difficulty()` should have been `pick_diff()`

other than that it works great.